# Управление потоками. Java. Wait() и Notify()

Tags: java, многопоточность

Данная мне задача состоит в создании двух потоков, один из которых записывает значение в переменную, а другой после него считывает это значение и выводит. Итерация повторяется заданное количество раз (number). В задании нельзя использовать wait() с параметром, yield() и sleep(). Не совсем понимаю, почему вывод после запуска моего кода показывает совершенно другую картину(потоки меняются местами), да и строк с выводом должно быть четное количество(2*number), что не всегда так на практике. Буду благодарен любому совету.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int number;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the amount of iterations:");
    number = in.nextInt();

    CommonResource resource = new CommonResource(5);

    Thread readingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public synchronized void run() {
            System.out.println("The 2nd thread has read value " + resource.getX());
            notify();
        }
    });

    Thread writingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public synchronized void run() {
            resource.setX(resource.getX() + 1);
            System.out.println("The 1st thread has applied value " + resource.getX());
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    writingThread.start();
    readingThread.start();

    for (int i = 0; i < number - 1; i++) {
        writingThread.run();
        readingThread.run();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Что такое CommonResource? Вряд ли операции set\get атомарны

Answer (score 0):

Цикл нужно поместить внутрь кода, выполняемого в тредах. Но главное: вам нужно синхронизовать потоки по общему монитору и на нём вызывать `wait()` и `notifyAll()`.

Что-то вроде этого:

```
Thread readingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int readsNumber = number;
            while (readsNumber > 0) {
                synchronized (resource) {
                    try {
                        resource.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.println("The 2nd thread has read value " + resource.getX());
                    resource.notifyAll();
                }

                readsNumber--;
            }
        }
    });

Thread writingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public synchronized void run() {
            int writesNumber = number;
            while (writesNumber > 0) {
                synchronized (resource) {
                    resource.setX(resource.getX() + 1);
                    System.out.println("The 1st thread has applied value " + resource.getX());
                    resource.notifyAll();
                    try {
                        resource.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                writesNumber--;
            }
        }
    });

    readingThread.start();
    writingThread.start();
```